Error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.__TAURI_IPC__ is not a function" when registering tauri Hotkey
So, i'm making an app which has a counter as its core functionality. I need there to be a Hotkey that increments a counter by 1, which also works if the app window is not in focus. For this, I resorted to global hotkeys. I have tried multiple times through rust and also directly through JS to implement a global hotkey with tauri's tools and have gotten the same error every time, so clearly i'm doing something wrong.
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import {showComponent} from '../store'
    import { register } from '@tauri-apps/api/globalShortcut';

    export let url:string;
    export let name:string;

    let count = 0;

    onMount(() => {
        const setupListener = async () => {
            await register('CommandOrControl+G', () => {
            console.log('Shortcut triggered');
            });
        };
        setupListener();
    });
    
    function closeHuntingScreen(){
        showComponent.set(false);
    }
    

</script>

This is what the JS part of my svelte module looks like, in which the counting should happen. I have adjusted the tauri config file as such:
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "globalShortcut": {
        "all": true
      }
    },

The Error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.TAURI_IPC is not a function" appears as soon as the module is opened and it stems from the register function, as far as I can see. I also tried this in rust:
use tauri::Manager;

// the payload type must implement `Serialize` and `Clone`.
#[derive(Clone, serde::Serialize)]
struct Payload {
  message: String,
}


#[tauri::command]
fn test_app_handle(app: tauri::AppHandle) {
    app.emit_all("event-name", Payload { message: "Tauri is awesome!".into() }).unwrap();
}

// Also in main.rs
fn main() {
  tauri::Builder::default()
  .setup(|app| {
   
 
    use global_hotkey::{GlobalHotKeyManager, hotkey::{HotKey, Modifiers, Code}, GlobalHotKeyEvent};

    let handle = app.handle();

    // initialize the hotkeys manager
    let manager = GlobalHotKeyManager::new().unwrap();
    
    // construct the hotkey
    let hotkey = HotKey::new(Some(Modifiers::SHIFT), Code::KeyD);
    
    // register it
    let _ = manager.register(hotkey);
    
    if let Ok(event) = GlobalHotKeyEvent::receiver().try_recv() {
        println!("{:?}", event);
        test_app_handle(handle);
    }
    


    Ok(())
})
    // This is where you pass in your commands
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("failed to run app");
}

And then called it like this in the frontend:
<script lang="ts">
    import {showComponent} from '../store'
    import { listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event'
    import { WebviewWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'


    export let url:string;
    export let name:string;

    let count = 0;

    const webview = new WebviewWindow('window');

    onMount(() => {
        const webview = new WebviewWindow('window');
        const setupListener = async () => {
            await webview.listen("event-name", e => {
                console.log("goteem: ", e)
                count++;
            });
        };
        setupListener();
    });
    function closeHuntingScreen(){
        showComponent.set(false);
    }

Same error, at the same place. What am I doing wrong?
